# Listbox filtering using a combo box

Tags: python, python-2.7, combobox, listbox, tkinter

I'm trying to filter the content that is displayed in my listbox depending on the currently selected item of a combo box. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this and I have not found even a simple, plain example online. Any ideas? I'd really appreciate some help.

Here are code excerpts.

Listbox:

```
class MyListBox(object):
    def __init__(self, frame, listbox_header, listbox_list):

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=listbox_header, show='headings')
    yScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame,orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
    yScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=yScroll.set)
    self.tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, expand=TRUE)
    for col in listbox_header:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
    self.update_rows(listbox_list)
    self.tree.bind('<Double-1>', self.OnDoubleClick)

def update_rows(self, listbox_list):
    items = self.tree.get_children()
    for item in items:
        self.tree.delete(item)
    for item in listbox_list:
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)

def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
    item = self.tree.selection()[0]
    self.Info(self.tree.item(item, 'values'))

#Single student information window. Display all courses in student listbox
def Info(self, selected):
    info = Toplevel()
    info.title('Student Information: %s - %s - %s' % (selected[0], selected[1], selected[2]))
    info.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, 50, 50))

    student = session.query(Student).filter_by(id=selected[0]).first()

    #Single student header label info
    Label(info, text='Total All Attempts: %s' % student.gpa).pack()
    Label(info, text='Total Best Attempts: %s' % student.best_gpa).pack()
    Label(info, text='Spec GPAs: %s' % student.rules_gpas).pack()
    Label(info, text='Spec GPAs Needed: %s' % student.rules_gpas_needed).pack()

    #Single Student course info list
    Label(info, text='\nAll Courses:').pack()
    current = session.query(Course.sid, Course.term, Course.subject, Course.number,
                            Course.title, Course.grade, Course.grade_val, Course.hours).\
        order_by(Course.term.desc(), Course.subject, Course.number, Course.grade_val.desc()).filter_by(sid=selected[0])
    course_header = ['ID', 'term', 'subject', 'number', 'title', 'grade', 'grade_val', 'hours']

    #setup listbox and scroll bars
    tree = ttk.Treeview(info, columns=course_header, show='headings')
    yScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(info, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
    yScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    tree.config(yscrollcommand=yScroll.set)
    tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

    for col in course_header:
        tree.heading(col, text=col.title(), command=lambda c=col: sortby(tree, c, 0))
        tree.column(col, width=50, anchor='center')
    tree.column('title', width=150, anchor='w')
    for item in current:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
```

And here is the combo box:

```
# This creates the drop menu (combobox)
Label(top, text='View Concentration:').pack(side=LEFT)
box_value = StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(top, textvariable=box_value, state='readonly')
titles = []
titles.append('All')
for rule in rules:
    titles.append((rule.title))
box['values'] = titles
box.current(0)
box.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you are trying to do is clear and repopulate the listbox every time the combobox changes. Surprisingly, it's not too difficult.

Here is my example app. It utilizes root.after to recursively check to see if the combo box has changed. Note that there is probably a way to bind the update function to the `StringVar.set` command, I just don't know what it is. You could also subclass with the StringVar, but regardless:

```
# Import
import Tkinter
import ttk

# Class
class App:

    # Init
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = ["All", "Odd", "Even"] # Combobox elements
        self.values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # Treeview elements

        self.last_filter_mode = "" # Combobox change detector

        self.create()

    # Build GUI
    def create(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk() # Can be substituted for Toplevel
        self.root.title("Filtered Listbox")

        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.root)
        # I like to use pack because I like the aesthetic feel
        # pady is 5 so that the widgets in the frame are spaced evenly
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", padx=10, pady=5) 

        self.filter_mode = Tkinter.StringVar(); # Combobox StringVar
        # Set it to the initial value of combobox
        # Also consider using self.options[0] for uniformity
        self.filter_mode.set("All") 

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self.frame, textvariable=self.filter_mode, state="readonly",
            values=self.options)
        self.combobox.pack(fill="x", pady=5)

        # So that the scroll bar can be packed nicely
        self.treeview_frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.frame)
        self.treeview_frame.pack(fill="x", pady=5)

        column_headings = ["A", "B", "C"] # These are just examples 
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(
            self.treeview_frame, columns=column_headings, show="headings")
        self.treeview.pack(fill="y", side="left")

        self.treeview_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self.treeview_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.treeview.yview)
        self.treeview_scroll.pack(fill="y", side="right")
        self.treeview.config(yscrollcommand=self.treeview_scroll.set)

    # Recursize update function called with root.after
    def update(self):
        filter_mode = self.filter_mode.get()

        # Check for change in the filter_mode
        if filter_mode != self.last_filter_mode: 

            items = self.treeview.get_children()
            for item in items:
                self.treeview.delete(item) # Clear the treeview

            # Combobox options
            if filter_mode == "All": 
                for element in self.values:
                    self.treeview.insert("", "end", values=(element))

            if filter_mode == "Odd":
                for element in filter(
                    lambda x: True if x % 2 != 0 else False, self.values):
                    self.treeview.insert("", "end", values=(element))

            if filter_mode == "Even":
                for element in filter(
                lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False, self.values):
                    self.treeview.insert("", "end", values=(element))

            self.last_filter_mode = filter_mode # Update current filter mode

        self.root.after(100, self.update) # Call this function again

    def main(self):
        self.update() # Start the recursive update function
        self.root.mainloop() # Start the app

a = App()
a.main()
```

I know it's a little bit complex, and integrating it into your current code may be difficult, but if you have any questions feel free to ask! Hope this helps!